# Quotients by algebraic group actions at the level of the Grothendieck ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory, grothendieck-rings

$\DeclareMathOperator\SGro{SGro}\DeclareMathOperator\Gro{Gro}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$For an algebraically closed field $K$, the Grothendieck semiring of $K$ consists of, say, quasi-projective $K$-varieties, modulo piecewise isomorphisms (with constructible pieces). The class of the variety $X$ is denoted $[X]$. Addition is disjoint union, and product is variety cartesian product. The Grothendieck ring the corresponding "enveloping ring". Denote them $\SGro_K$ and $\Gro_K$.

Let $G$ be a linear (reductive?) algebraic group acting on a quasi-projective variety $X$. **My question** is whether there is a well-defined element, which I'd denote "$G\backslash [X]$" in $\SGro_K$, or at least in $\Gro_K$ (with some properties described below).

Roughly speaking, the issue with quotients is that they behave poorly in the category of varieties. For instance, if the multiplicative group $K^*$ acts on $K$ by multiplication, then the ring of invariants is trivial, so in some sense the variety quotient is a point, but on the other hand the set-theoretic quotient consists of 2 points (2 orbits), and if one splits $K$ into its invariant subsets $K^*$ and $\{0\}$, the quotient is now a pair of points, which is the quotient I want to define. Similarly, for $K^*$ acting on $K^2$ by multiplication I would expect to obtain $[\mathbf{P}^1\cup\{\cdot\}]=[\mathbf{P}^1]+1=[\mathbf{A}^1]+2$.

More precisely, I'd expect the quotient to satisfy:

1. if the variety quotient $X\to G\backslash X=Y$ behaves well, i.e., is the setwise quotient at the level of $K$-points, then $G\backslash [X]=[Y]$
2. if $X$ is partitioned into finitely many locally closed $G$-invariant subsets $X_i$, then $G\backslash [X]=\sum_i G\backslash [X_i]$.

So, if there exists such a partition such that each quotient $G\backslash X_i$ behaves well, one could, in principle, define the $G\backslash [X]$ as $\sum_i [G\backslash X_i]$, hoping it does not depend on the choices. (I'm happy to assume that $K$ has characteristic zero if it avoids pathologies or simplifies the picture.)

Let me now give a concrete motivation. Consider the variety $L_n\subset\mathbf{A}^{n^3}$ of Lie algebra laws on $\mathbf{A}^n$. The group $\GL_n$ naturally acts on $L_n$. Classifying $n$-dimensional Lie algebras over $K$ is the same as classifying $\GL_n(K)$-orbits on $L_n(K)$. This set is usually defined as a bunch of points and varieties modulo finite group actions, but no rigorous meaning is given to this structure.

For instance for $n=3$ the list consists of a one-parameter family and a few additional laws. Depending on the description, some given Lie algebras can be, or not, part of the 1-parameter family, and the number of remaining Lie algebras can differ. But it seems that the class in the (semi-)Grothendieck ring should be $[\mathbf{P}^1]+4[\{\cdot\}]$.

I have more complicated cases in mind, e.g. 7-dimensional nilpotent Lie algebras, for which this consists of 6 rational curves and about 160 additional points.

Comment: What about using some stacky Grothendieck ring instead?

Comment: One could indeed work in the Grothendieck (semi)ring of algebraic stacks, and map $X$ and $G$ to the class of the quotient stack $[X/G]$. However this doesn't satisfy the property (1) that was asked for in the question, for example with $\mathbb G_m$ acting on $\mathbb A^2$ one would get the class $L^2/(L-1)$ rather than $L+1$.

Comment: More generally the class of $[X/G]$ in the Grothendieck ring of stacks is completely insensitive to the action of $G$ on $X$, when $G$ is a special algebraic group such as $\mathrm{GL}_n$, and in this case $[X/G]=[X]/[G]$. Ekedahl shows in his first paper on the Grothendieck ring of stacks that the Grothendieck ring of stacks is isomorphic to the Grothendieck ring of varieties localized at $L$ and $L^n-1$ for $n>0$.

Comment: (That should have been $L+2$ in my first comment, i.e. the class of $\mathbb P^1 \sqcup \{\mathrm{pt}\}$.)

Comment: My rough intuition is that allowing constructible decompositions avoids the need to go beyond varieties. Am I wrong? All that's needed is that every irreducible variety with $G$-action has an open dense $G$-invariant subset on which there is a quotient variety such that fibers of the quotient map are exactly $G$-orbits. Is this true, or too optimistic?

Comment: @YCor I think it is possible, I was rather responding to Qiaochu's comment. (Though I think the notation $G\backslash [X]$ doesn't really make sense - $G$ acts on $X$, not on $[X]$...)

Comment: @DanPetersen I know, it was precisely a notation I introduced, so it made sense by definition :) it might be inconvenient and I'm happy to switch to another one. (Actually I started with $[G\backslash X]$ but found the latter one much more confusing since it can be in conflict with established meanings for $G\backslash X$, or suggest $G\backslash X$ makes sense while it's not).